# How do we insert dynamic image attribute inside the append in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div with id `test`. When trying to append the `img` tag inside the div I just get `[object HTMLImageElement]`. Is there a way I can get my image inside `#test` div using `append`.

```
image_tag = document.createElement("img");
image_tag.setAttribute("alt", test_alt);
image_tag.setAttribute("class", test_class);
image_tag.setAttribute("src", test_src);


$("#test").append("<div class='test-class'>\
  <a class='t1' href=" + href_path + "?locale=test" + " target='_blank'>\
    <div class='head-test'>\
    image_tag //Display image here
  </div></div\);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you know the HTML markup of the image, you may be able to simply concatenate that into the string passed to `.append`:

```
$("#test").append(`
<div class='test-class'>
  <a class='t1' href=" + href_path + "?locale=test" + " target='_blank'>
    <div class='head-test'>
      <img alt="${test_alt}" class="${test_class} src=${test_src}
    </div>
  </a>
</div>`);
```

You can also turn the inserted markup into a jQuery collection beforehand, use `appendTo` to insert it at the proper place, then `.find` the nested `head-test` and append the image to that:

```
$(`<div class='test-class'>
  <a class='t1' href=${href_path}?locale=test target='_blank'>
    <div class='head-test'>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>`)
  .appendTo("#test")
  .find('.head-test')
  .append(image_tag);
```

(this second method is safer, because it

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `image_tag` is coming from some other source. If that is not the case then you can simply add `img` tag in your html and provide the attribute the way that you have done for `anchor` tag

```js
var image_tag = document.createElement("img");
image_tag.setAttribute("alt", "Some Alt");
image_tag.setAttribute("class", "SomeClass");
image_tag.setAttribute("src", "SomeSource");

var href_path = "Some Path";

var html = "<div class='test-class'>  <a class='t1' href='" + href_path + "?locale=test' target='_blank'>    <div class='head-test'> "+ image_tag.outerHTML +" </div></div>";

$("#test").append(html);
console.log(html);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```